# Add my browser name in useragent

Tags: android, android-webview

I used User agent `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; One Build/KTU84L.H4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/56 Mobile Safari/537.36` that show my user as chrome 56, if I edit that it shows default Android `webView` or Android Browser. But I want to show my browser name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change user-agent :

```
 WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
 settings.setUserAgentString(" MY BROWSER ");
```

This is just a string , it is still chrome ;)